# How to index design formula elements in DESeq2?

Tags: r

Here is an example:

```
cts<-matrix(sample(1:1000, 600, replace = T), ncol=6)
rownames(cts)<-paste0("Gene", 1:100)
colnames(cts)<-paste0("sample", 1:6)

coldat<-data.frame(B=c(1,2,1,2,1,2),
                   C=c(1,1,1,2,2,2))
rownames(coldat)<-colnames(cts)

library(DESeq2)
batch="B"
condition="C"
dds <- DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData = cts,
                              colData = coldat,
                              design= ~ batch + condition)
dds <- DESeq(dds)
Error in DESeqDataSet(se, design = design, ignoreRank) : 
all variables in design formula must be columns in colData
```

My question is how to index `batch="B"` and `condition="C"` in the `design` formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figured out:

```
dds <- DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData = cts,
                              colData = coldat,
                              design= as.formula(paste0("~", batch, "+", condition)))
```

Comment: If this has worked, accept as answer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `batch` and `condition` are not esplicitly declared in `coldat`. If `B=batch` and `C=condition`, then you can simply `~ B+C`. Otherwise you will need to add (or rename) the 2 columns.

```
coldat$batch <- coldat$B
coldat$condition <- coldat$C
```

or, if they differ

```
coldat$batch <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
coldat$condition <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2)
```